# Pagination WordPress theme

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm building my own theme for WordPress, but now I'm stuck because I need add the pagination to the blog post page. I attached HTML code where I want add the PHP code for pagination.

```html
<ul class="justify-content-center">

    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>

</ul>
```

I'm using the WordPress function "pagination_links", but how can I get each number created inside the "li" tag?

Answer (score 1):

[paginate_links()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/paginate_links/) is the function. If you check the WordPress documentation for this function it does mention an argument `'type'` which controls format of the returned value. Possible values are 'plain', 'array' and 'list'. Default is 'plain'. For your case function will be as following:

```
paginate_links(array(
  'type' => 'list'
));
```